# How to perform setState() while listening to a Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I hope you are doing well. I was looking for a way where I can perform setState within a Stream. Basically what I am doing here is, I am getting the data from the collection, assigning it to a List variable called currentDocuments and I am displaying it in a ListView.builder(). I did not use StreamBuilder because, the documents can be deleted, but have to be deleted locally and not from firestore.
The problem is when I add a new document to 'mycollection' collection, I get this message:

> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree. This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

I have tried a lot of ways using 'mounted' field, but still, I get the message mentioned above. Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
_subscription = Firestore.instance.collection('mycollection').snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for(var i in querySnapshot.documentChanges){
        if(i.type == DocumentChangeType.added){
          if(!mounted){
            setState((){});
          }
          setState(() {
            currentDocuments = querySnapshot.documents;
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_subscription = Firestore.instance.collection('mycollection').snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for(var i in querySnapshot.documentChanges){
        if(i.type == DocumentChangeType.added){
          if(mounted){
            setState(() {
             currentDocuments = querySnapshot.documents;
            });
          }
          
        }
      }
    });
```

here mounted will be true if the widget exists in the tree, but in your code there are two setState calls which will fire either the mounted is true or not!!, use/call setState only when mounted is true,